# Evolution email: is there a chance to get HTML Signature in line with the sending alias?

Tags: email, evolution

Is there any chance to have multiple signature in Evolutions (yes) and automatically attach a one signature to a given alias?

I have a single mail account with two aliases and I'd like to attach the right signature automatically when the alias changes and not by remembering to do it manually.

I can see there is a script to author the output, but the challenge is still trapping the sending address?
Any idea?